# Cant retrieve userid for external page (moodle)

Tags: moodle

I have an external page in moodle, I would like to use the userid in the page.

The page has a link to the moodle config (from what I have been told to do) but it just isn't working.

Any idea what else I would need to do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that by userid you mean the current user id, a minimal approach to a page that can retrieve the current user id would be:

```
<?php
require_once(__DIR__ . '/config.php'); // Assuming the page is in the root dir.

$PAGE->set_context(context_system::instance());
$PAGE->set_url('/mypage.php');
$PAGE->set_title('My title');
$PAGE->set_heading('My heading');

echo $OUTPUT->header();
echo $USER->id; // Here we go!
echo $OUTPUT->footer();
```

Notice that $USER is one of those bootstrapped Moodle global objects (like $DB, $PAGE and so on) and do not require any kind of instantiation.

Also, don't forget that the current user may not be logged in and in that case $USER will be a representation of a guest user with a "fake" ID (not related to any user in database).

Comment: Thanks Mitxel, that looks about right for what I need. I am assuming the header() retrieves the moodle header and footer? I do plan to right a catch for none logged in users. I am guessing passsing that userid into a sql_fetch_array will be ok?

Comment: @NeilNorris indeed, the output of the header and the footer are not needed and neither the page setup (set context and so on) if you don't plan to print a usual Moodle page. Also, if you are going to work with the Moodle tables/database I recommend you to use the Moodle data manipulation API (a high level interface to work with the database) to read/write from database, since once you require the config file you can use both the $DB methods as well as the $USER object right away.

Comment: All done and created Mitxel, starting to get the hang of moodle/php now! Thanks alot!